# WP 8.1 Inheritance from Page

Tags: xaml, inheritance, windows-phone-8.1

There is any way to change Page for a custom class that inherits from Page? I mean in a XAML.

Thank you.

Comment: *Page* class is not *sealed* so you can extend it. What do you mean 'in XAML'? Any examples?

Comment: Create a new page in a WP proyect, you will get a file xaml with a .cs associated, the XAML is a <page..., you can't change it to a custom page, gives error, and you can't change the .cs because it is a partial class and gives error.

Comment: I've added a sample of a Page extended with INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your extended *Page* class in XAML then you have to exchange all clases of this page - in XAML and partial classes in code. A sample example:

```xml
<shl:PageWithNotify
  x:Class="MyProject.Pages.MyPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:shl="using:AppExtensions">
  <shl:PageWithNotify.Resources>
      .. some more code
```

The page class defined in AppExtensions:

```cs
public class PageWithNotify : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    // rest of your code
```

And the partial Page class in code:

```cs
public sealed partial class MyPage : PageWithNotify
{
    // your code
```

Comment: Lol I'm stupid, I didn't tried with <local:... even having xmlnslocal=... defined haha

Comment: Mm.. now Visual Studios gives error, says that my custompage it is not in the namespace... but it is not true! And I can't compile... and before it was running, wtf?

Comment: @BlackCid I'm not sure. Do you have in the same project the class or in additional reference library? Try to clean project, rebuild.

Comment: It is an universal solution, and the class is in the shared part. Still I don't understand why during a time it have been compiling (even running in the emulator) and now gives error.

Comment: @BlackCid Try restart visual studio, also manually delete bin and release/debug folders (try to clean the solution). I'm not sure what could have happened.

Comment: Mm... I was adding a custom panel and it makes Visual Studio start to say that, so weird but if I remove it everything goes nice. Well, now I have to see what is happening with the custom panel hehe